# Create symbol using unicode characters

Tags: unicode

How would I go about creating the following symbol in unicode?

[image: Desired image]

The closest I've gotten is [U+9712 (WHITE SQUARE WITH UPPER LEFT QUADRANT)](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/9712):

[image]

Is there any way I could use a combining character to get the result I'm after?

Comment: You can't strictly "create the symbol in unicode" if it doesn't already exist. All you can do is to try to find a matching character (and font that contains it). (Or create your own font?)

Comment: Ah, ok. I was wondering if there was any way to combine existing characters, such as U+9712 and, say, [U+119355](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/119355). If this isn't possible I'll look into creating a custom font, but I'd prefer to do this using existing characters.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry... there are special [combining characters](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) (including [diacrtics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)). However, I'm not sure that you can combine _arbitrary_ characters, which this would seem to require? (I was thinking that you could perhaps have a _negative space_ (a backspace-type character) followed by another character to effectively _overtype_, but I can't find any reference to this?) Maybe SVG would be an alternative?

Comment: Just for exactness of terminology:  [an individual Unicode code point is expressed as `U+n`](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/UnicodeStandard-9.0.pdf), where `n` is four to six **hexadecimal digits**, using the digits 0–9 and uppercase letters A–F (for 10 through 15, respectively). You should use `U+25F0` and `U+1D23B` instead of their decimal values `9712` and `119355`, respectively.

Answer (score -3):

Just press *Alt* + *9 7 1 2*
This is good,

> Bad

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What do you mean by good/bad?

Comment: I do not understand this post. Without more information this doesn't appear to be a legitimate attempt to answer the question.